# Access 2013 Query Count

Tags: ms-access

I have to do a query that shows training completion dates for all employees. The end result would be the number of employees that attended company trainings each quarter.

I have setup the query to have the user enter a start and end date for it (example 1/1/17 - 3/31/17) which works and a total row which also works. The issue I am having is I only want the count to include the records that fall within that range.

EXAMPLE

```
Employee Name    Training1    Training2  Training3   Training4
Noname           07/06/17     1/12/17    2/15/17      6/6/17
COUNT            1            1          1             1
```

I know the query above is right because 2 pieces of the record fit the puzzle however, 2 pieces do not. How can I make my query work to only count what fits in the given date range? So COUNT should be 0, 1, 1, 0?

Comment: Try providing more information about the query you are using for someone to provide better help.

Comment: Provide example of raw data structure. Post the query SQL statement.

Comment: I was able to figure this out though I am not sure if I did it properly. In the end I only wanted a count of each training provided in a quarter and nothing else.

What I did was create a query with a start and end date parameter (the user will chose the range) for each of the trainings located in the training table and added a field called type. This will pull all of the records for a training within the required time and the training name.

Comment: Next I created a union query that pulls the results from the individual queries. I created a query off of my union query and added a column for each training to display the name of the training using  OnlyBB: IIf([Type]<>"Bloodborne",Null,[Type]). 

From this I created a report that had a label for each training and a =count(*) for each column. This gave me exactly what I needed